# Aero-Peek during Alt-Tab Not Working

Tags: windows-7, aero-peek

I have recently set up a new install of Windows 7 and I have just noticed that when alt-tabbing I am not getting Aero-Peek previews as I am accustomed.

I have checked to make sure that aero-peek is enabled in both the taskbar properties (and taskbar icons do show previews!) as well as in system performance settings.  Both are enabled.

I even looked at a couple of registry edit solutions, but the key I am supposed to edit is not present (adding it did nothing).  Even Alt-Tab Tuner hasn't solved the problem.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you installed the latest graphics drivers?

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove Yes. The driver was issued two weeks ago.

Comment: and you've tried looking in the registry for: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM
See the right side, you'll find a DWORD value called EnableAeroPeek and set it to 1?

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove It is already set to 1.

Comment: one more troubleshooting step: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976170

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove "Troubleshooting couldn't identify the problem."

Comment: Are you looking for 'Win+Tab' ?

Comment: @RogUE No, good sir.  I am not.  That continued to function perfectly throughout my ordeal.  (And I don't like it).  I already solved my own problem, as well, see below.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to perform a clean boot on the computer and check if any of the 3 party programs are causing the problems. Make sure that you put the computer back in normal startup after clean boot troubleshooting.

To perform a clean boot on a computer that is running Windows 7:

[kb929135](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135)

Comment: Sadly...that didn't help.  Even under a clean boot I didn't have aero preview during alt-tab.

Comment: @Draco18s What version of Windows 7 are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Pro. And yes, it was legally purchased.

Comment: Just checking, will keep looking as this is not typical win7 pro behavior.

Comment: Thanks. And yeah, when I noticed it I was like, "that's odd" and everything I knew about it and everything I could find didn't work.  I am not even positive that it was *ever* working correctly.

Comment: @Draco18s http://www.sevenforums.com/themes-styles/294226-dreaded-aero-peek-not-working-2.html#post2763625

Comment: I re-ran the assessment (it was 2 days old), no change.  The value for "graphics: windows aero" is 5.3 and the aero-preview option in properties is not grayed out and already selected.

Comment: I go gaming for an evening and I come home to find that it works now.  WTH.  Only thing I can think of that I did after getting home that would have even come close to affecting this was rebuilding the icon cache (because a program in my start menu had a generic icon, rather than it's program icon).

Answer (score 0):

I have both discovered the *cause* and the *solution* to my issue.  I had wondered about the cause earlier, but it was such tenuous speculation I didn't even mention it.

Installing Dropbox broke Aero Peek.

Fixing it requires doing the following:

- [Rebuilding the Windows icon cache](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/wrong-or-missing-program-icons-in-windows-7-start/3fb5be69-105a-40ca-a0ca-695b8bad41f8)
- Restarting the computer

Does not appear that the order matters, as the first time I fixed it I'd previously restarted the computer to no effect and as soon as I rebuilt the icon cache, it worked.  After reinstalling Dropbox (in an attempt to get it to locate its executable anywhere but the C drive), rebuilding the icon cache was insufficient and as soon as I restarted the computer, it worked.

Computers run on black magic. That's the only explanation as this entire series of events *makes no sense.*